# как зашарить сайт на xampp локально?

Tags: apache, xampp, share

есть сайт, который находится по адресу:
    `C:\xampp\htdocs\localsite`
как сделать так, чтоб этот сайт был доступен локально в обычной домашней сетке со всех компов?

Answer (score 1):

```
Listen 8008

<VirtualHost *:8008>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/localsite"
  ServerName 192.168.XXX.XXX
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/localsite">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Как то так вроде. В **alias.conf** порт и адрес меняете на свой любимый. Хотя уже не особо помню как правильно. Ну и смотреть чтобы порты не были закрыты на компьютере с сервером и что firewall не блокирует.
А вообще вроде же по умолчанию можно зайти на сайт просто по адресу компьютера в лан сети, без добавления чего либо в конфиги.